# Displaying a nested data with a conditional: How can I not display the data whose product's color is not according to the conditional?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display all the quantity of colors that are more than 10. It does display it, however, this will also display even the products whose colors are less than 10. How do I fix this? Thank you.

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/products-0ccdhk?file=/src/App.js:752-1189

```
 {product &&
        product.map((item, i) => (
          <ul key={i}>
            <li>{item.id}</li>
            <li>{item.prodName + " " + item.size}</li>
            {Object.entries(item.colorMap).map((color) => (
              <>
                {color[1] > 10 && (
                  <>
                    {color[0]} - {color[1]}
                  </>
                )}
              </>
            ))}
          </ul>
        ))}
```

Currently, this is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{product &&
    product.map((item, i) => {
      const obj = item.colorMap;
      for (let x in obj) {
        if (obj[x] > 10) {
          return <li key={i}>{item.prodName + " " + item.size}</li>;
        }
      }
    })}
```

Link CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/products-forked-mtt94c?file=/src/App.js:752-1008

Because you used "=> ()" in map method, it returned whole items in your product array. I replaced it as "=> {}" and returned with a condition in "{}".

You can also write like this:

```
export default function App() {

  const newProduct = product.filter((item) => {
    return Object.values(item.colorMap).every((color) => color > 10);
  });

  return (
    <ul className="App">
      {newProduct &&
        newProduct.map((item, i) => (
          <li key={i}>{item.prodName + " " + item.size}</li>
        ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```